# Delete all HTML elements from page using Find and Replace with regex

Tags: visual-studio

I've got a large number of `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` server controls that I want to delete from multiple webforms pages. It's too tedious to remove them all by hand.

How can I create a regex to use in Visual Studio's Find and Replace dialog?

[image]

I'd like to remove the server control entirely. In the example below, it'd leave an empty table cell.

[image]

Currently

```
<td>  
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator attr1=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
</td>
```

Leaving only (whitespace not necessary to remove):

```
<td></td>
```

Comment: If you have a version of Visual Studio that supports Macros, you might find them easier and quicker (and funner) to use.  Years ago I create a Video tutorial that shows how they work: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=fbec4e587d5fa39a&id=FBEC4E587D5FA39A!113

Comment: You can use Notepad++ for that, it supports regex search and Find In Files functionality.